# jQuery Set CSS properties from multiple fields

Tags: jquery, css

I have a form which contains around 40 varying fields (selects, radios, inputs etc), these fields contain values which are to be applied as CSS properties (for example: a text input field for colour would take a hex code).

I've already got a working version which uses the id of each field and attaches it to a variable and then I pass the variable to the CSS property of the element I want to change on keyup, something like below.

```
function elementStyles(){
    var bgcolor = $("input#id_bgcolor").val();
    var color = $("input#id_textcolor").val();
    var marginbottom = $("input#id_margin_btm").val();
    var borderradius = $("input#id_border_rad").val();

    $("h2").css({
        "background-color": bgcolor,
        "color": color
    });

    $("div").css({
        "margin-bottom": marginbottom,
        "border-radius": borderradius
    });
}

$("input, select").on("change keyup, function(){
     elementStyles();
});
```

My question is, what is the most efficient way of getting all of the form item values, bearing in mind their order and amount is likely to change in future. I also have no way of altering the markup to add data-attributes.

Is it a case of just manually targeting all 40 properties?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this... Here's one:

You could create a map between the IDs and their corresponding elements and properties:

```
var idMap = {
  'id_bgcolor': {
    'element': 'h2',
    'property': 'background-color'
  },
  'id_margin_btm': {
    'element': 'div',
    'property': 'margin-bottom'
  },
};
```

Then, you can loop through the map, getting the values and setting them in a couple loops:

```
var inputIds = Object.keys(idMap);
var elements = {};
for (var i = 0, z = inputIds.length; i < z; i++) {
  var $input = $('#' + inputIds[i]);
  var value = $input.val();
  var mapping = idMap[inputIds[i]];
  var element = elements[mapping.element] || {};
  var property = mapping.property;
  element[property] = value;
  elements[mapping.element] = element;
}
var elementNames = Object.keys(elements);
for (var e = 0, z = elementNames.length; e < z; e++) {
  $(elementNames[e]]).css(elements[elementNames[e]]);
}
```

Here's another, if you can add `data-` attributes (which I'm chagrined to see that you can't):

Add the name of the CSS property as a `data-` attribute to the elements. For instance:

```
<input class="style" data-element="div" data-attribute="margin-bottom" type="text">
<input class="style" data-element="h2" data-attribute="background-color" type="text">
```

Then in `elementStyles`:

```
$('.style').each(function (item) {
    var $item = $(item);
    $($item.data('element')).css($item.data('attribute'), $item.val());
});
```

That way, you're just defining each of them once. You do end up making more calls to `.css()`, but those are generally fast enough. If you find it slowing down, you could compile all of the attributes for a particular element a la:

```
var elements = {};
$('.style').each(function (item) {
    var $item = $(item);
    var element = elements[$item.data('element')] || {};
    element[$item.data('attribute')] = $item.val();
});
var elementNames = Object.keys(elements);
for (var e = 0, z = elementNames.length; e < z; e++) {
    $(elementNames[e]]).css(elements[elementNames[e]]);
}
```

There you're building up the objects for setting in `.css()`, then doing them all at once.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately adding data-attributes isn't possible (form is created via an object), although the above would be perfect.

Comment: You might want to add all of your requirements to your question. Then people won't waste time on answers that won't work for you :).

Comment: Hi Mike, I did state that in the second-to-last paragraph.

Comment: One of these days I'll get new glasses :).

Comment: After all that, it might be easier just to write out the code for 40 properties :).